# React Select: Does not show the selected values in the field after closing the dropdown

Tags: reactjs, npm, filter, use-state, react-select

Good evening, i'm using this npm for selecting mutiple values: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select

A issue is occurring after choosing multiple values. The select compoment do not show the selected values if I close it and opening it again. The function works but I dont know why the values isn't showing afterwards. I would like to allow a user to see their selected choices and continue to add or remove values without losing it when they close it.

Code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-stonebraker-vx73t?file=/src/App.js

Any reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot wrap the react-select with the MUI select, that's causing the react-select to go on and off from the DOM, and every time it is back it's empty as the state it holds gets reset.

If you check the [documentation](https://mui.com/components/selects/#main-content) from MUI select you can tell it is intended to have MenuItem elements inside, not other things.

TL;DR, just don't wrap react-select with the MUI select and you should be fine.

Comment: Yeat that make sense, but after changing it. I tried to do something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/begzd?file=/src/Populate.jsx:2227-3825. But in my sandbox example it still doesn't work accordingly.

Comment: now you have a diff issue, just remove the value prop from your react-select, like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-lewin-vlyz0, PS: if you find my help useful plz accept it as the answer, ty!

Comment: btw, why do you have the menuIsOpen prop set, is that on purpose? Maybe consider removing it as having those select options displayed by default does not seem a good approach in terms of usability.

Comment: For that purpose, it is simply to give users an indication of what they can search on. However the selected value do indeed show up, but the selected value reset when i'm closing the dropdown. That is sort of the problem i'm trying to figure out.

Comment: check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-lewin-vlyz0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks, a simple but good solution